# Do users of my web application need to manually enable native-client on their browser

Tags: c++, plugins, web-applications, google-nativeclient

I'm building a web application and i want to use c++ code on my client side. Most answers i've gone through suggest using native client.

What i want to know is, will the people using the web app need to go and enable native client manually in their browser, or is it done automatically.

If it has to be done manually, is there a better way to use c++ code in the browser without having the user to carry out extra steps?

Comment: `c++` comes in long after you've figured out the answer to your question. "_c++ code in the browser_" sounds interesting though.

Comment: Isn't this what WebAssembly is for? I think that is enabled by default on modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Native Client is [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/migration), and should not be used for new projects. WebAssembly is what you should use, as it works on all modern browsers. [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) is the easiest way to build C++ code to WebAssembly and integrate it into your web app.